# Fast alternative to `appendChild`

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, atom-editor

#### Question

Is there a fast alternative to `appendChild` when the elements are large?

```js
const output = parent.appendChild(child);
```

This single function call blocks the main thread of my app making it very slow.

#### Background

In the [`minimap-lens`](https://github.com/iyonaga/minimap-lens) package for Atom, I need to append an element to the editor element. However, doing this operation is very expensive and can take ~1 min for the large editor elements (>1500 lines). I think that is because the chromium engine needs to calculate the exact size of DOM elements before doing this.
It happens at this line: [`appendChild`](https://github.com/iyonaga/minimap-lens/blob/5cb03d093d06bea3865536a307270bb8090f3750/lib/minimap-lens.js#L301)

```js
    const parent = atom.views.getView(atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor())
    const output = parent.appendChild(child)
```

Comment: You can use websockets to prevent blocking the main thread

Comment: Have you tried appending a placeholder child first and only setting the `innerHTML` content for it afterwards? I have no idea whether that's faster, just throwing it out there as something to try.

Comment: @Raphael do you have an example that allows dom-manipulation using WebSockets?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I think setting the `innerHTML` converts my child to a string. I tried `const output= parent.appendChild(document.createElement('div')); output.innerHTML = child;` however, the inner result is `[object HTMLDivElement]`.

Comment: Amin: yes, sounds like `child` is an object, so you would have to try `output.innerHTML = child.outerHTML`.

Comment: I think he means web workers, not websockets.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I tried a couple of combinations such as setting the innerHTML,/outerHTML from innerHTML/outerHTML of the original element or the placeholder child. This seems twice faster. However, it does not work! The lens does not show correctly. I might have to play more with this approach. Doesn't doing this break the DOM updating connections? Originally, my child shows the editor content as the editor changes.

Comment: @Loïc Web workers do not allow DOM manipulation as I remember.

Comment: 1min sounds suspiciously to me. Do you append these elements one by one? That way, it reflows entire dom each time. Create wrapper or fragment (not appended yet), append all childs to this element and then append parent/fragement to dom => 1 reflow. You can also wrap all of this to async function to unblock main thread.

Comment: Wait, which element are you adding (contents, and where)? 1 minute is absurd, and though “>1500 lines” is technically a big range, the small lower bound makes it sound like things are not pariticularly big.

Comment: @bigless the exact time depends on the number of lines and CPU power. The child itself is one element. It is a [copy of the editor element](https://github.com/iyonaga/minimap-lens/blob/5cb03d093d06bea3865536a307270bb8090f3750/lib/minimap-lens.js#L264). So the element is large! I have already done a lot of optimization like caching and it is wrapped in a `requestAnimationFrame`. So this happens only once, but still takes a lot of time in the beginning.

Comment: @Ry-  The child is a copy of the editor element appended to the editor. As parent changes the child also changes. The exact code is here: https://github.com/iyonaga/minimap-lens/blob/5cb03d093d06bea3865536a307270bb8090f3750/lib/minimap-lens.js#L188-L195.  Check `prepareCreateLens` and `createLens`

Comment: One element with 1500 lines of text shouldn't be an issue. It sounds more like a bug.. Did you try to profile (devtools performance tab)?

Comment: @bigless The editor element includes other decorations and styles in addition to simlpe text. I wonder if there is a way to cut out the extra things. Calling `editorView.clientHeight` takes a long time, which makes me suspicious that a lot of size calculation is done inside `appendChild`. Yes. I did a lot of optimization by measuring each function and line of code. However, there is no way to replace `appendChild`. I found the exact line of code using `const t = window.performance.now(); code; console.log(window.performance.now()-t1)`

Comment: I benchmarked the clientHeight calculation again. That is fast, so the issue is not height calculation.

Comment: I would try to interpolate that bottleneck simply. Create vanilla example . Append exactly same content to div without any editor/plugin/jquery. Just simple example. If it will be still slow, share fiddle. If not, there is a bug.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that the calculation of `minimap` dimensions takes a lot of time. I already optimized that somewhere else that was needed. But here since `minimap` is also a child of the parent. I am very suspicious that this is causing issues.

Comment: Is there a way to inform the engine about the size of the minimap element? Because that is something I know indirectly. But I think the DOM engine does not!